# Natural language to propositional logic

Tags: logic

I have to translate the following sentences into propositional logic:

> 1. Magnus moves the tower or bishop, unless Magnus moves his knight.
> 2. A sufficient condition for the product of two integers being even, is that at least one of them is odd.

For the first I did the following: $p_0:=$Magnus moves the tower or bishop, $p_1:=$agnus moves his knight. Then, it's translation is $\neg p_1\implies p_0.$ But I'm not sure because we have a disjunction in $p_0$; should I decompose it? Meaning, $p_0:=$Magnus moves the tower, $p_0:=$Magnus moves the bishop, $p_2:=$agnus moves his knight. Then, $\neg p_2\implies (p_0\vee p_1).$ But if I do this, then in natural language it translates to "Magnus moves the tower or Magnus moves the bishop, unless Magnus moves his knight." Which is different to the given.

For the second one, I have kind of the same problem. Let $p_0:=$ One of the integers is odd. $p_1:=$The product of both integers is odd. Then $p_0\implies p_1$. The conflict that I have is that $p_0$ does not captures that both could be odd; using "at least" could help, but seems like there is a disjunction there; should I decompose it?

Comment: ""Magnus moves the tower or Magnus moves the bishop, unless Magnus moves his knight." Which is different to the given." How so?

Comment: Yes, you should decompose in both cases.

Comment: In a syntactically way. Or it doesn't matter as long as it means the same?